# Android app to log network requests

Tags: android, networking, monitoring, network-monitor

Can anyone recommend an [android](/questions/tagged/android) app that will log all network requests?

*The log must include the following data:*

- The name of the app that made the request
- The date/time the app made the request
- The destination of the request
- HTTP and HTTPS requests

*Ideally, but not required, I would also like the log to include:*

- Whether or not the connection was actually made (e.g. the Response Code)
- If the connection request was made to a URL, the IP address for that URL according to the system's DNS
- If the connection request was made to an IP address, a reverse lookup of that IP address to one or more URLs
- Parameters of the request
- Requests made using all protocols

*Not needed:*

- Encryption of results
- Stealth logging
- Password protection
- Uploading the results to a server
- Emailing the results

The software must be compatible with Android KitKat.  Root apps are fine.

I would prefer an app that can be completely disabled when not in use.

I have a preference for [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) and [open-source](/questions/tagged/open-source) recommendations, but neither is required.

Comment: I'm also looking for such app...

Comment: If you are rooted, you can use adaway to log all the network requests. Open the app, in the menu choose Log DNS Requests. You can download adaway from F-Droid or, apk is available on XDA.
It can log all the DNS requests system wide. If you want app specific requests, start the logging and open the app, you will know the requests made by that app. You can turn it on/off any time. It is compatible with kitkat. It's free and open-source. 
But it doesn't have many of the features you have asked for, that's why I am writing this in the comment section. You can completely disable it when not in use.

Comment: @BarathVutukuri LOL... that's exactly what I'm doing now. :-)  The downsides are that it's missing many of the important features above (as it's not designed for this use!) and it alphabetizes the list of requests, making it impractical to see their order... plus blocked requests are not listed at all.

Comment: Not checked for all of your requirements, but many [Firewall apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_firewall) include logging AFAIR.